# Parallelizing the Bone matrix computation when calculating the Final Bone matrix i Hirerachy

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

ReadNodeHeirarchy finds the interpolation value for translate,rotate & scale at a given TimeStamp, so every time Frame calculate these values at fed them onto GPU for Final Transformation of each bone.
Is there anyway to Optimize the code?have anybody tried to move this computation onto GPU ?

```
void Mesh::ReadNodeHeirarchy(float AnimationTime, const aiNode* pNode, const Matrix4f& ParentTransform)
    { 
        string NodeName(pNode->mName.data);

        const aiAnimation* pAnimation = m_pScene->mAnimations[0];

        Matrix4f NodeTransformation(pNode->mTransformation);

        const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim = FindNodeAnim(pAnimation, NodeName);

        if (pNodeAnim) {
            // Interpolate scaling and generate scaling transformation matrix
            aiVector3D Scaling;
            CalcInterpolatedScaling(Scaling, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
            Matrix4f ScalingM;
            ScalingM.InitScaleTransform(Scaling.x, Scaling.y, Scaling.z);

            // Interpolate rotation and generate rotation transformation matrix
            aiQuaternion RotationQ;
            CalcInterpolatedRotation(RotationQ, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim); 
            Matrix4f RotationM = Matrix4f(RotationQ.GetMatrix());

            // Interpolate translation and generate translation transformation matrix
            aiVector3D Translation;
            CalcInterpolatedPosition(Translation, AnimationTime, pNodeAnim);
            Matrix4f TranslationM;
            TranslationM.InitTranslationTransform(Translation.x, Translation.y, Translation.z);

            // Combine the above transformations
            NodeTransformation = TranslationM * RotationM * ScalingM;
        }

        Matrix4f GlobalTransformation = ParentTransform * NodeTransformation;

        if (m_BoneMapping.find(NodeName) != m_BoneMapping.end()) {
            uint BoneIndex = m_BoneMapping[NodeName];
            m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].FinalTransformation = m_GlobalInverseTransform * GlobalTransformation * 
                                                        m_BoneInfo[BoneIndex].BoneOffset;
        }

        for (uint i = 0 ; i < pNode->mNumChildren ; i++) {
            ReadNodeHeirarchy(AnimationTime, pNode->mChildren[i], GlobalTransformation);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is recursive and GPUs are very bad at running recursive code or loop statements. So you have to tune your logic in such a way that GPUs can take it and give you better performance.

You are actually confusing 2 different problems here.

1) Calculating global matrix for all nodes, which has to be recursive based on the scene graph. This is a CPU problem and not a GPU thing, as recursion it the best way for this.

2) Actual interpolation and vector math. This can be sped up by using SIMD optimised code which will give you 4x speed boost for all your vector math operations.

For your problem I would suggest using SIMD optimisations.

Note: Am writing something very similar to what you have posted here. Using Assimp and OpenGLES for iOS & Android.

Comment: for SIMD Operations  are you using any 3rd party library? . Am using glm for matrix multiplication which seems to be SIMD optimized

Comment: GLM should be fine for SIMD, but I've used my own version of SIMD optimisation derived from Apple's GLK Library which is much faster than GLM. To render the Mesh with skin, I am using GPU skinning, which mean, I do all interpolation on CPU and send the global matrix of all bones in uniform array .

Comment: yeah i do the same but send it as a texture cause on Low end QualCom chips they have only 240uniforms

Comment: In that case, you can do CPU skinning. Which is also working fine for me. I've done both on my Rendering Engine. If the number of bones are more than the device's capability my code will fall back to CPU skinning.

Comment: One huge difference in how am doing it is, Am converting all animation information into my own keys and interpolating them. Am using Assimp only for loading the file.